# fade fade out effect need for existing javascript code provided

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, fade

Is it possible to apply a fade in fade out effect to javascript code please?

At the moment it just pops up an image and disappears with no effect applied. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FadeIn() and FadeOut() needs a duration set, like FadeIn("slow"); or FadeOut("fast"); or even in milliseconds like FadeIn(3000); otherwise the fade effect is'nt really a fade effect as it happens instantly.
The setInterval() function only loops the fades.

Comment: not quite sure how this works sorry I havenet got a fade in fade out yet? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I assumed you where using fades as the page you linked to uses jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut, and it's almost at the top of the source in a setInterval function. Visit jQuery pages and have a look at those funtions, they are fairly easy to apply to an image, and there's always this site if you run into problems.

Comment: Heres updated code but still does not work... http://jsfiddle.net/5mpfY/10/ Thanks very much adeneo for your help so far..

Answer (score 1):

Since your site is already using jQuery, look into using jQuery [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) functions.

```
$('div').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below script

```
function gradient(id, level)

{

    var box = document.getElementById(id);

    box.style.opacity = level;

    box.style.MozOpacity = level;

    box.style.KhtmlOpacity = level;

    box.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + level * 100 + ")";

    box.style.display="block";

    return;

}



function fadein(id) 

{

    var level = 0;

    while(level <= 1)

    {

        setTimeout( "gradient('" + id + "'," + level + ")", (level* 1000) + 10);

        level += 0.01;

    }

}

function centerPopup()
{
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    //alert(windowWidth); alert(windowHeight);
    var popupHeight = 300;
    var popupWidth = 400;
    //alert(windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2); alert(windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2);
    document.getElementById(AnyElement).style.top = windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2 + 'px';
    document.getElementById(AnyElement).style.left = windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2 + 'px';
} 

function openbox(fadin)

{
    var box = document.getElementById(AnyElement);
    document.getElementById(AnyElement).style.display = 'block';

    if(fadin)

    {

        gradient("box", 0);
        fadein("box");
        centerPopup();

    }

    else

    {   

        box.style.display='block';

    }
}

function closebox()

{

    document.getElementById(AnyElement).style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById(AnyElement).style.display = 'none';

}
```